# Custom selector for data in jQuery don't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, custom-selectors

I have elements in the DOM that have set `data('disabled', true)` and I want to create custom selector that will select those elements. I try this:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], { 
    disabled: function(a,i,m) {
        return $(a).data('disabled') === true;
    }
});
```

and this:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].disabled = function(a,i,m) {
    return $(a).data('disabled') === true;
};
```

I also try `!!$(a).data('disabled');`

but it don't work, `$('.parent :disabled')` return nothing, even when I have elements that are inside `.parent` that have `data('disabled')`. Anybody know why.

Comment: jquery already has a selector [:disabled](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is because jQuery already has a selector named :disabled, if you rename it it works fine

```
jQuery(function($){
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], { 
        disabled1: function(a,i,m) {
            console.log('x',arguments)
            return $(a).data('disabled') === true;
        }
    });

    $('.parent :disabled1').hide()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/geNdx/)